# pythonのnumpyでベクトルどうしの掛け算をしたい

Tags: python, numpy

numpyで以下のような処理をしたいと思っています。

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])

x = np.zeros(3,3)

for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    x[i,j] = x[i,j] + a[i]*b[j]
```

この例の場合だと

```
x = [[1*4, 1*5, 1*6], [2*4, 2*5, 2*6], [3*4, 3*5, 3*6]]
  = [[4, 5, 6], [8, 10, 12], [12, 15, 18]]
```

を算出したいです。
np.matmulを使うと1×4+2×5+3×6=32となってしまいます。良い方法はないでしょうか。

またもし可能であれば、最終的には

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [10,20,30]])
b = np.array([[4,5,6], [40,50,60]])

x = np.zeros(2,3,3)

for k in range(2):
  for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
      x[i,j] = x[i,j] + a[k,i]*b[k,j]
```

を行いたいと思っています。kは数万程度、i,jは数千程度です。
もし良い方法や高速に計算できる方法をご存じであれば、教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: np.matmulでご自身でやった時のコードも追記しておいてください

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])

result = a[:, None] * b
print(result)

#
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [12, 15, 18]])
```

> 最終的には

```py
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [10,20,30]])
b = np.array([[4,5,6], [40,50,60]])

print(a[:,:,None] * b[:,None])

#
array([[[   4,    5,    6],
        [   8,   10,   12],
        [  12,   15,   18]],

       [[ 400,  500,  600],
        [ 800, 1000, 1200],
        [1200, 1500, 1800]]])
```